# How to use subsubsection in Beamer class?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

As I give academic courses — and not presentations —, I have to divide very precisely the sections of my courses. In order to do this, I need to use subsubsection which appear in the toc. How could I do that? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}


    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{frame}{outline}
    \tableofcontents    
    \end{frame}

    \section{A title}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: How to use subsubsection with Beamer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\subsubsection` in exactly the same way as `\section` and `\subsection`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\hspace*{3em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{outline}
\tableofcontents    
\end{frame}

\section{Section title}
\begin{frame}{Section frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsection frame}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\begin{frame}{Subsubsection frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]